# How to do OAuth authentication in Twitter using fabric

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

This is the first time I am doing social integration as a part of an assignment given to me. I am trying to make a twitter like app. But I have a query. To access Twitter API, the documentation says I need oAuth tokens. What I am getting is object of `TwitterAuthToken`. Is it the same as OAuth token? I am using fabric for developing this app. Kindly help.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/application-owner-access-tokens

Comment: I have written tutorial for twitter login you can check at - http://www.androprogrammer.com/2016/01/fabric-sdk-for-twitterlogin.html
hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: So I picked some code from the link you provided. And it is getting verified. But how do I call a twitterapi using the token as it is giving me bad authentication data.